Join with a double entry dataframe
I am trying to create a variable based on the amount of years and the scoring of a contract. This double-entry table contains the two main variables:



scoring
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11




9.3
0.00805%
0.0283431%
0.0283431%
0.0464484%
0.0464484%
0.0464484%
0.1196343%
0.1196343%
0.1562273%
0.1562273%
0.2595363%


9.2
0.0102%
0.0102%
0.0476431%
0.0875944%
0.0875944%
0.0875944%
0.0875944%
0.1434739%
0.1434739%
0.2072495%
0.2072495%


9.1
0.0383297%
0.0835863%
0.0835863%
0.0835863%
0.0835863%
0.0835863%
0.1810753%
0.1810753%
0.2259184%
0.2259184%
0.2259184%



Expected result:

I need to do the same with this database:
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[80887618
,80887619
,80887620
,80887621
],
'years': [9,
1,
5,
12

],
'scoring': [9.3
,9.2
,9.1
,9.3
]
})


IIUC, you unstack the dataframe with the percentages, then merge it into df:
percentages = (
    percentages.set_index("scoring")
    .unstack()
    .reset_index(name="data")
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "years"})
)

df = df.merge(percentages, how="left")

         id  years  scoring        data
0  80887618      9      9.3  0.1562273%
1  80887619      1      9.2     0.0102%
2  80887620      5      9.1  0.0835863%
3  80887621     12      9.3         NaN

